# non-binary convolutional codes

Tags: matlab, trellis

Is there any way to adapt the matlab convolutional encoders/decoders to work with non-binary data (i.e., real numbers)? I am trying to construct a trellis of an encoder where the input bits are binary, but the output codewords are real numbers.

Any hints?

Comment: Maybe you can apply just convolution (function `conv`) for the encoder. That depends on how the encoding is done. For the decoder, I do'nt think `vitdec` works for thast case, but I'm not sure. I'm curious, what's the application of this? Equalization?

Comment: Yes, equalization.

Comment: Then maybe [this](http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/mlseeq.html) can help? (I've never used it)

Comment: @LuisMendo Looks very useful. I will try it in the morning and come back. You may want to add it as an answer to this question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is useful. Thanks @LuisMendo

Comment: Good! I didn't post an answer because it would only be a link. If you feel like it, maybe explain your application a little more and post an answer